# Keyframing Clip Threshold does not update on viewport

Tags: animation, materials, shaders, keyframes

I'm using Eevee and I'm controlling a shader through the alpha clip threshold under Settings in the Material Properties tab. If I right click on the "clip threshold" slider I can keyframe it, but while the value changes if I scroll through the frames, it still won't update in the viewport.
I noticed that the clip threshold slider doesn't have the "animate property" diamond on the right. But still, if I keyframe it, the value will be animated, just not rendered.

Any ideas? Maybe a bug?

Blender version is 2.90.1

Comment: 2.93 is out, so maybe they fixed that, but it does sound like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when I render the animation, the clip threshold is actually working, even though it won't show in the viewport when playing the animation through the timeline.
I guess the solution is to just rely on the final rendered animation, instead of the viewport.